# Problem with the body field after upgrading to 7.7

Tags: 7, upgrading

I recently upgraded to 7.7 because of the security updates, but now, when I try to add content there is no body field... and when I go check the module list I see [this message](http://pastebin.com/GnjuE3Gp) on top of the list.

> Notice: Undefined index: module in _field_info_prepare_instance_widget() (line 382 of /var/www/gisele-drupal/modules/field/field.info.inc).
>       Notice: Undefined index: module in _field_info_prepare_instance_display() (line 350 of /var/www/gisele-drupal/modules/field/field.info.inc).
>       Notice: Undefined index: module in _field_info_prepare_instance_widget() (line 382 of /var/www/gisele-drupal/modules/field/field.info.inc).
>   […]

Does anyone know what could be going on here, and how can I solve this?

Comment: You may want to use drupal's issue queue and not stack exchange for problems like this as describe in the FAQ. Did you review this issue queue node? http://drupal.org/node/1062142

Answer (score 2):

Are you using OG?  Because that could be causing the issue.

Things to do

1. If OG is installed, but not enabled delete it.
2. Clear Cache
3. Update all modules up to their most recent versions
4. Run Update.php (do whenever a module is updated or deleted)
5. Uninstall Views and reinstall it

Issue about this problem here > http://drupal.org/node/1001060

Comment: not using OG. All modules and core are updated... the message no longer shows up but I still don't have my body field displayed

Comment: your best bet is to check the issue que link above

Comment: I did it Chris, hopefully I'll get a response but I am not holding my breath.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the core issue, there is also a problem with Entity Reference: http://drupal.org/node/1329354.  I'd recommend doing some disabling (as suggested) to determine which of these bugs is the culprit.